# Endorsement policy in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am using Hyperledger Fabric version 1.2. I have created a channel with 1 orderer and 10 peer nodes, all belonging to the same organisation. I want to instantiate the chaincode with the endorsement policy such that all the peers of ORG1 are the endorsing peer, not just 1. What is the valid expression for the same?

Currently using the following policy:

```
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051" cli peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C mychannel -n chainname -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":[""]}' -P "AND('Org1MSP.member')"
```

[Fabric documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/endorsement-policies.html) contains examples of including peers from different organisations.

Answer (score 2):

**This can be achived while invoking the chaincode. You have to pass the peer addresses of all the peer nodes who you want to act as endorsing peers**

peer chaincode invoke -o orderer0.abc.com:7050 -C abcchannel -n fabcar --peerAddresses peer0.org1.example.com:7051 --peerAddresses peer1.org1.example.com:7051 -c '{"Args":["initLedger"]}'

Comment: I think @flair his question was how to mention the endorsement policy while instantiating

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately! there no valid command for that, you can follow two steps if you want to achieve this:

1. Write your own custom endorsement logic by a plugin. This method is little cumbersome and you can follow this link if you want to do that. [Pluggable endorsement and validation logic](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/pluggable_endorsement_and_validation.html)
2. Or, you can have an alternate solution by creating 10 Orgs with 1 peer each and define the endorsement policy through the command that you want as:

   > `-P "OutOf(10, 'Org1.peer', 'Org2.peer', ...., 'Org10.peer')"`

But, having all the peers as an endorsing peer is never a good idea as if a peer goes down, you will have to face serious problems as no transaction will be committed